# jquery set tabindex and cursor

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

I have the following code that assigns tabindex to my form id "register1". I would like to place the cursor on the first input or select list item on the form (item with tabindex = 1) once tabindexes are assigned. but the following line: `$('#register1').find('input').attr('tabindex',1).select();`
Resets tabindex of all the inputs.

Full code:

```
$(function(){
    var tabindex = 1;
    $('#register1').find('input,select').each(function() {
        if (this.type != "hidden") {
            var $input = $(this);
            $input.attr("tabindex", tabindex);
            tabindex++;
        }
    });
    $('#register1').find('input').attr('tabindex',1).select();
});
```

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try :

```
$('#register1').find('input[tabindex=1]').whatyouwant()
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply select the item with tabindex one in your loop using a condition:

```
$(function(){
    var tabindex = 1;
    $('#register1').find('input,select').each(function() {
        if (this.type != "hidden") {
            var $input = $(this);
            $input.attr("tabindex", tabindex);

            // select the first one.
            if (tabindex == 1) {
               $input.select();
            }
            tabindex++;
        }
    });
});
```